# Installing Rpy2 on MAC

Tags: macos, r, easy-install, rpy2

I am trying to install Rpy2 on OSX using easy_install.
`sudo easy_install rpy2`
I am getting an error message:

`Running rpy2-2.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-du_3ue/rpy2-2.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-GqSaS7
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
R was not built as a library`
Invalid substring`

`in string`

`error: Setup script exited with Problem while running` `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags`

I am guessing the problem is with R as it is not sharing its library.
I am using Python 2.7 and R 2.15.2
Please help!

Comment: It may be worth checking easy_install is installed correctly, it appears make is not available: `make: command not found`

Comment: You probably need to install Apple's developer tools (Xcode, AFAIR).

Answer (score 0):

Install using macports (https://www.macports.org)

sudo port install py27-rpy2

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need the XCode command line tools - the `make` command isn't there by default, and weirdly enough, current XCode doesn't install the command line tools by default. Go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads (it'll tell you to make a developer account by signing in with your Apple ID - don't worry, it's free, unlike the App Store developer license). Find `Command Line Tools` for your version of macOS and Xcode, download, and run the installer.